# Laravel Raw Statement Where I can select from different table based on if a column data is equal to another

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, phpmyadmin

I'm using the bellow code to select and collect data from Bookings table.

```
public function collection()
{


    return Booking::select(
        'id',
        'place_id',
        'payer_name',
        'user_fullname',
        'user_email',
        'user_phone',
        'user_no_of_guest',
        'user_no_of_babies',
        'user_checkin',
        'user_checkout',
        'is_approved',
        'user_promo',
        'user_payment_type',
        'user_booking_tracking_id',
        Booking::raw('(created_at +  INTERVAL 2 HOUR) AS created_at'),
        'paid_ammount'

    )->get();
}
```

The database I'm collecting from is this one [bookings Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGg4W.png), The table that I want data from is this one [promo_codes Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCJNm.png).

I want to select promo_codes.promo_type, where booking.user_promo == promo_codes.promocode, if that makes any sense, sorry if the question is a bit confusing, but thats the best I was able to explain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query -

```
public function collection()
{
    return DB::table('bookings')->select(
        'id',
        'place_id',
        'payer_name',
        'user_fullname',
        'user_email',
        'user_phone',
        'user_no_of_guest',
        'user_no_of_babies',
        'user_checkin',
        'user_checkout',
        'is_approved',
        'user_promo',
        'user_payment_type',
        'user_booking_tracking_id',
        Booking::raw('(created_at +  INTERVAL 2 HOUR) AS created_at'),
        'paid_ammount',
        'promo_codes.promo_type'
    )->join('promo_codes', 'booking.user_promo', '=', 'promo_codes.promocode')->get();
}
```

Comment: I tried a similar approach, and now tried yours, but it's returning empty data.

Comment: And in order for it to work, I have to add "booking.", before each column name.

Comment: It should return empty data if there isn't any promo code in promo_codes table. Consider using `leftJoin` in place of `join` . Let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: The only problem, is the Booking::raw line is not working anymore, and giving error, any idea as of why?

Comment: `DB::raw('(bookings.created_at + INTERVAL 2 HOUR) AS bookings_created_at'),` - use this instead